# "better" score method for TransformedTargetRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) in scikit-learn does not score predictions as I would expect or desire. Best I understand, it calls the r2score function on the original `y` and the predicted `y_pred` after inverse-transforming the regressor's output. I'd much rather know the score of the estimator on the transformed `y` and regressor's output. Not shown below for simplicity, but I'd like to keep it all in a `Pipeline`, so I'm hoping there is a way to wrap `TransformedTargetRegressor` or pass a custom `score` method.

As setup for my specific question, take the following linear regression:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 1)
y = (2 * X).ravel() + np.random.normal(size=10)

estimator = LinearRegression()
estimator.fit(X, y)
estimator.score(X, y)
```

I would appreciate suggestions for modifying or wrapping the `tt` estimator below so that it produces an **identical** score as the above.

```py
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

ey = np.exp(y)
tt = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=estimator, func=np.log, inverse_func=np.exp)
tt.fit(X, ey)
tt.score(X, ey)
```